# React-material AppBar and theme

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, electron

I try to add theme to my react app  but when I add like so:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#556cd6',
    },
    secondary: {
      main: '#19857b',
    },
    error: {
      main: red.A400,
    },
    background: {
      default: '#fff',
    },
  },
});
```

And then :

```
 <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
```

I got error in AppBar component

```
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '100' of undefined
>     at renderer.dev.js:4524
>     at transformedStyleArg (renderer.dev.js:18657)
>     at handleInterpolation (renderer.dev.js:1631)
>     at serializeStyles (renderer.dev.js:1756)
>     at renderer.dev.js:2100
>     at renderer.dev.js:909
>     at renderWithHooks (renderer.dev.js:64339)
>     at updateForwardRef (renderer.dev.js:66398)
>     at beginWork (renderer.dev.js:68452)
>     at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (renderer.dev.js:53299)
```

in this line

```
const backgroundColorDefault = theme.palette.mode === 'light' ? theme.palette.grey[100] : theme.palette.grey[900];
```

theme.palette.grey is undefined

Comment: of course is undefined because there is no `grey` property in `pallete`

Answer (score 0):

```
const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    grey: {
      main: '#808080'
  },
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Comment: this doesn't help. maybe I did something  wrong. this is the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/example-material-demo-forked-smo39?file=/demo.tsx